# Selecting Data from SQL Database Returns "1"

Tags: php, mysql, select

This is my first SQL Database. I've been able to successfully connect to my server and database. But, when I use a query to select data from one of the columns in my table, it returns the number "1". Why is this?

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT Item FROM Items";
$result = $conn->query($sql);   

echo "<h1>Connected successfully<h1>";
echo "<p class='lead'>" + $result + "</p>";

$conn->close();

?>
```

Here's an image of the table named `Items`

[image]

This is what shows up on the webpage where it should `echo` the contents in the `item` column:

[image]

Comment: Is this a SQL Server database or a MySQL database?

Comment: From `mysqli::query` page: *"Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just echoing the whole object, not individual rows. You need to do something like this to iterate over each row.

```
if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        echo "<p class='lead'>" . $row[0] . "</p>";
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because 2 different things:

1. You are trying to concat a string with the `+` simbol not with the `.` simbol.
2. Your `$result` variable contains a `mysql_result`, because the query was executed.

If you want to echo your data you must to use `$result` into a `while loop`.

Comment: mysqli::query returns a mysqli_result on successful return from a SELECT query not true. Where does the bit about echoing a color come from - the query on selects the Item column - and if as you suggest $result contains true then $result["Color"] would be invalid.